# Subsetting a matrix using a vector of indices

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix of values, and a vector which tells me, for each row of the matrix, which (one!) column I'd like to access. How, without a loop, do I retrieve those values?

Data:

```
dta <- structure(c(0.02, 0.01, 0, 0.08, 0.18, 0.01, 0.12, 0, 0.03, 0, 
                   0.95, 0.96, 0.94, 0.97, 0.98, 0.95, 0.99, 0.91, 0.96, 0.98, 
                   0.98, 0.99, 1, 0.92, 0.82, 0.99, 0.88, 1, 0.97, 1, 
                   0.05, 0.04, 0.06, 0.03, 0.02, 0.05, 0.01, 0.09, 0.04, 0.02), 
                 .Dim = c(20L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("1", "2")))
```

Vector of indices:

```
idx <- c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)
```

Desired output:

```
0.98
0.98
0.99
0.91
0.82
0.99
0.88
0.99
0.96
0.99
0.95
0.96
0.94
0.96
0.97
0.94
0.98
0.91
0.96
0.97
```

Background: `e1071::cmeans` returns `membership`, the membership values of all points to all clusters, and `cluster`, the most probable cluster. I would like a vector of the membership values of the most probable clusters to generate transparent colors for a cluster plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
dta <- structure(c(0.02, 0.01, 0, 0.08, 0.18, 0.01, 0.12, 0, 0.03, 0, 
                   0.95, 0.96, 0.94, 0.97, 0.98, 0.95, 0.99, 0.91, 0.96, 0.98, 
                   0.98, 0.99, 1, 0.92, 0.82, 0.99, 0.88, 1, 0.97, 1, 
                   0.05, 0.04, 0.06, 0.03, 0.02, 0.05, 0.01, 0.09, 0.04, 0.02), 
                   .Dim = c(20L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("1", "2")))

idx <- c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)

dta[cbind(1:nrow(dta), idx)]
```

I clearly assume that `length(idx) == nrow(dta)`. If they are not equal, R will stack idx as many times as necessary to have the same amount of elements as we have rows. So if you leave out the last element of `idx` you get

```
idx <- c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)
dta[cbind(1:nrow(dta), idx)]

[1] 0.98 0.99 1.00 0.92 0.82 0.99 0.88 1.00 0.97 1.00 0.95 0.96 0.94 0.97 0.98 0.95 0.99 0.91 0.96 0.02
```

where the last element is picked from column two instead of one since R started at `idx[1]` again.

Comment: You are correct, the vector is of the same length as the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Or alternatively:

```
c(dta[which(idx==2),2], dta[which(idx==1),1])

# [1] 0.98 0.99 1.00 0.92 0.82 0.99 0.88 1.00 0.97 
# 1.00 0.95 0.96 0.94 0.97 0.98 0.95 0.99 0.91 0.96 0.98
```